# C# Bar chart. Change size once bar, change color bar, change value bar

Tags: c#, bar-chart

I have question: how on the component bar chart in Windows Form Application C#, changes properties single bar (size, color, value). I would like changes made by properties.

Please give an example.

Comment: Could you please try to explain this in a bit more detail? For me it is very unclear what you're actually asking for... Also have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code to show that might help us understand where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: I have to create custom chart component and I want to have access to properties of every single bar.

Comment: Well when you're creating a custom chart component then it is all up to you how you implement it... Or are you talking about using the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control? It is still not very clear what your actual problem is... Could you please try to explain it again more clearly with more details (preferably in more than just 1 sentence)?

Comment: By use System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Comment: Please have a look at the following Stack Overflow post, and then try editing your question accordingly: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy!

Step1: On the chart properties you should find **Series** and click on ... icon

Step2: On the Series window you should find Points icon and click it.

Step3: Here you should add points and configure them as you want. (Color, X Value, Y Value.. )

Hope this helps.. Good luck!